# Is there an option to message a member privately or to contact by email?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is there a way to contact a member privately, like on Facebook; or to contact by email?

Comment: There is the chat engine, but that is just as public as the main site. You need 20 rep to use the chat room and I think 2000 to create your own room. Again, they are still public. Everyone with a web browser can see them.

Comment: See [the official response to this suggestion on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/145951).

Comment: @Caleb I've read that El'endia Starman already mentioned that in his comment. I think my request partially has been answered with the capacity to use chat. The reason I'm asking this is because I want to create a chat discussion on specific theological controversy. Asking one question at a time is too slow, I believe chat is a better way to answer particular question. I don't think my request is denied per se because chat is partially answering my question. So instead of labelling it as denied, you can say partially answered. Because on Facebook we can chat with multiple people.

Comment: @AdithiaKusno I marked this as [meta-tag:status-declined] because the exact question you asked has been very specifically declined by Stack Exchange Inc. There is no way to contact other members privately or to look up their email addresses. Both particulars are very specifically not going to be implemented. If a public chat room serves some of your purposes, that's neither here nor there—I'm glad it does but that isn't what you asked here. BTW, if you get a topical discussion going in chat we can spawn a separate room for it—but remember the main purpose of this site is QnA, not social.

Answer (score 4):

No.

I suggest spending some time looking at the available Help pages, found under the Help link at the top of the page.  These will give you an idea of how this site is intended to work and how it (and all the other related SE sites) are different from social media sites.

One key point to keep in mind is that this site is part of a much larger network of Q&A sites, and many of the norms, features, and functions are based on network-wide experience and discussion.  There is [a special meta site for questions/requests that apply to the whole network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), and if you go there you'll find multiple requests for a way to contact other users - but they've all been rejected.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not a social media. That's why I ask if such feature can be implemented.

Comment: @AdithiaKusno: If it was desirable to implement this feature, the developers would have done so long ago. There's probably a post on MSE about why they didn't... **EDIT:** Yup, here: [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)